# Convert php to jQuery for XML?

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have an XML feed that i have to pull in to my server using php. The final line is this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
```

I am using a pretty standard method to read a test XML test file using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "abc.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
```

My question is, how do I replace jQuery's abc.xml with php's $xml variable? Is this accepted practice?

I'd be OK to write this file to my server every few hours if that's the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Replace that line :

```
url: "abc.xml",
```

With something like that

```
url: "yourphpfile.php",
```

Don't forget to add

```
echo $xml;
```

At the end of your php file. **Don't echo anything else, anywhere in your php script.**

You can also add

```
header("Content-type:text/xml");
```

at the beginning of your php file.

Comment: Then, the content of `$xml = file_get_contents($url);` needs to be printed out

Comment: @emartel That what's "At the end of your php file, echo the $xml variable." means :p

Comment: Indeed, my ADD lead me to read the header part and expect the echo to be AFTER :)

Comment: Thanks guys, looks good. If I want yourfile.php to be in the home directory on my server, what is the jQuery version of php's <?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/home/yourfile.php"); ?>

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify that. How do I call yourfile.php if it's in /home/ on a Linux server?